# how to reindex an array by filling holes?

Tags: javascript

suppose I have an array (drawing top to bottom):

0
3
0
4
0

where 0 represents a "hole", I would like to reindex it like so:

0
0
0
3
4

meaning non zero cells "fall" to the bottom, like a tetris game.

how can I achieve this using only for loops and without shift/unshift/pop/any other array method?

height is known and static.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any other constraints to this (exercise-sounding) problem? For example: can you create a new array, or do you have to use the input array?

Comment: I need it to only iterate this array using for loops and change positions etc. The reason I'm so specific is that this needs to be ported to construct2, a 2d game creation engine, and it lacks array methods. I will convert the formentioned code to construct2 format myself.

Comment: `yourArray.sort(function(a, b){return b === 0 ? 1 : 0});` would work.

Comment: @Xufox `sort` costs O(n log n) and is not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Comment: Is this supposed to done in place? Can you use `sort`?

Comment: @torazaburo It seems the question wants to keep non-zero items in relative order, and that may not happen if you use non-stable sort. And my answer should be O(n), please tell me if I made any mistake.

Comment: Mark Canlas I can post a snippet of my construct 2 events if needed but this would be out of topic. And I'm 37 years old :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate backwards, keeping track of at which index you should move the next non-zero value.

```js
var arr = [0, 3, 0, 4, 0];
var idx = arr.length;
for(var i=idx-1; i>=0; --i)
  if(arr[i] !== 0)
    arr[--idx] = arr[i];
for(var i=0; i<idx; ++i)
  arr[i] = 0;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: If you want to distinguish `+0` and `-0`, compare using `Object.is`

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I used something different because of the limitations of construct 2, that works just fine :)